# Is there a way to load another vimrc file?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to use vim multi language IDE using alias.

```
alias vim-cpp='vim [load c++-specific vimrc file]'
alias vim-python='vim [load python-specific vimrc file]'
...
```

I know vim can identify filename extension so Vim doesn't need alias to make multi language purpose to itself. But that solution needs filename like "vim asd.c", "vim qwe.py".

Another problem is, I write functions in vimrc which compile and run automatically, and set a hotkey for this to F5, F6, ... . When I want to write WiringPi Programming with C which needs to add -lwirirngPi parameter when compile with gcc, that solution can't discriminate that current .c file is using wiringPi or not. So the function just do "gcc (filename).c -o (filename)" without -lwiringPi.

That's why I'm searching for alias and the parameter to load custom vimrc.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vim -u some_vimrc_file
```

lets you use another vimrc file instead of any .vimrc file